# Wpf, style is not being applied

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've written a user control with popup, who's content is being set outside the control. The ControlTemplate of that control looks like the following:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:InfoIcon">
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="HelpButton" Style="{StaticResource HelpButton}" />
        <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=HelpButton}" Placement="Bottom"
                IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=HelpButton, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" StaysOpen="False">
            <Border BorderBrush="#767676" BorderThickness="1" 
                    Background="#f1f2f7">
                <Border.Resources>

                    <!-- Important -->
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#575757" />
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#575757" />
                    </Style>
                    <!-- /Important -->

                </Border.Resources>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding HelpContent}" />
            </Border>
        </Popup>                                   
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The `Important` part - I want to assign custom styles to items, which are being put inside the popup (it serves as a clickable hint)

I'm using my control in the following way:

```
<local:MyControl>
    <local:MyControl.HelpContent>
        <TextBlock>Ala ma kota</TextBlock>
    </local:MyControl.HelpContent>
</local:MyControl>
```

But despite styles in the Border, `TextBlock`'s text's color always inherit the value from its parent (checked using Snoop) - resulting in white text on white background.

You can downlad the [small PoC application, which demonstrates the problem](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8B169EF451FFD9FE!932&authkey=!AMGIZf2Ou78Vr6k&ithint=file%2c.zip).

My observations:

- The styling **does** work for `Label`. It only doesn't work for `TextBlock`.
- When I add `TextBlock.Foreground="Red"` to the Border, `TextBlock` becomes red, still ignoring style (but now using color from Border).
- Snoop informs, that this `TextBlock` actually **has** the `Style` resolved correctly. But despite it [shouldn't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it uses the inherited value instead of one specified in the style.

How can I solve this problem and why does it occur?

Comment: as you know that your text block is child in visual tree so it will definitely inherit his property from parent. so if you want to have different color for text block apply the style to textblock where ever it is imported. to verify just change the colour at <TextBlock Style="MyStyle">Ala ma kota</TextBlock>

Comment: Sure, but I soon will have hundreds of these TextBlocks (possibly a few along with other controls). Should I always specify the style explicitly? Also, elements usually use styles, which are in resources of their ancestors, but in this particular case it doesn't. Why is it so?

Comment: just remove the style from parent so it will use the style defined in resources for child.

Comment: what's this stackpanel inside the ContentPresenter, this seems to not match with the code above.

Comment: I've put it there while testing to place multiple elements inside that popup. It's a simple `<StackPanel>`, no resources, etc.

Comment: thanks for the project, see my edit of the first answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I received answer on Microsoft forums; I'll leave it here in case someone encounters the same problem.

> The difference is that a TextBlock is not a control, i.e. it doesn't have any ControlTemplate and because of this the implicit style doesn't get applied to it when it is located inside the StackPanel. Please see the following page for more information:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/08/27/implicit-styles-templates-controls-and-frameworkelements.aspx
>
> You could use Label elements or set the style for the TextBlock elements explicitly.

**-- Magnus (MM8)**

Comment: the link leads to microsoft devblogs with unrelated articles (

Answer (score 1):

***Edit2***

I've set the Foreground of the `UserControl` to something else. This behavior is because the child `TextBlock` controls of the UserControl inherit the Foreground-Settings somehow. This has nothing to do with the popup or some other approaches we tried yet.

I've stumbled upon another question with a similar problems here: [Cannot override controls foreground colour in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297722/cannot-override-controls-foreground-colour-in-wpf)

I suggest to accept this strange behavior and just set a `Foreground` Color of the UserControl instead:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:InfoIcon}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

***previous Edit***

You had my curiousity with this weird behavior, but after looking at your PoC it was rather obvious :) The Popup has some attached Properties `TextElement.*` where you can style the text elements in the popup. This was new to me, too and I will reseach a bit more afterwards. Nevertheless: Workaround for your Problem is to not style the `TextBlock` but the `Popup` instead. your code could look something like following :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:InfoIcon}">
      <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Popup">
          <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
      </ControlTemplate.Resources>

      <Grid>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="TB" Width="16" Height="16"/>
        <Popup Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=TB}" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=TB, Path=IsChecked}" StaysOpen="False">
          <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding InfoContent}"/>
        </Popup>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I changed the styles to be outside of the controls, of course you can just use the attached properties of the popup directly. But initially you wanted to know how it works with the styles attached at the border, it does not matter now where you add the styles. You can use a ResourceDictionary for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these options solves my problem. The first doesn't work and in the second case, the contents of popup will differ - that's why I'm using ContentPresenter.

Comment: It bugged me that the ContentPresenter would not apply the styles. So I tried it by myself. And it worked without any problems, your error seems to be somewhere else. See following Demo for demonstration, perhaps you can compare this simplified one with your project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/awvpr3xfdjdcdq9/WpfApplication22.zip

Comment: I've tried to modify your application to match mine, but I coudln't break the style. On the other hand mine still doesn't work and I don't have a slightest idea, why. I'll include the screenshot from Snoop.

Comment: I've written a small proof-of-concept application, which demonstrates the problem. The link is in the question after edits.

Comment: That starts to make sense... but still, I'm putting styles in resources, which are *in* Popup and should take precedence over it! (Style in resources is being resolved *before* inherited values - if I didn't miss something)

Comment: yes this is not the final solution I guess. I removed the button and the popup in your poc and it was the same behavior. It seems like the `TextElement` Property is somehow set for your DependencyProperty `InfoContent` explicitly. But I found no such line in your project.

Comment: Moreover, I've got a control, which derives from textbox and has its own style applied. In style I define its Foreground color, but nevertheless Popup forces it to have the same color as its `TextElement.Foreground`.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion, shouldn't this:

```
TargetType="local:InfoIcon"
```

be like this?

```
TargetType="{x:Type local:InfoIcon}"
```

Comment: Ok, it might be more concrete. You use exactly TextBlock, not something inherited from TexBlock? Maybe there is some class named TextBlock? I asking because, we have such issue some time ago, when one 'smarty' added new class with name - Label.

Comment: I use TextBlock *and* another control derived from TextBlock and they both ignore style and both use inherited value instead of style. On the other hand, Label uses its style correctly.

Comment: From MSDN: In markup, you can specify a TargetType directly as the type name (or you can optionally use {x:Type...} to return a Type.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/412b1747-60e9-4b9a-8f8f-bd56f3aff875/applying-style-resources-to-contentpresenter-text?forum=wpf Maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some TextBlock style defining that it shouldd take the parent's control foreground.

Did you try to add a BasedOn property like this ?

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#575757" />
</Style>
```

Comment: It doesn't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code example and this works :

```
 <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding InfoContent}">
                                <ContentPresenter.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ContentPresenter.Style>
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
```

That's kind of odd because when I put the Foreground setter for the Label control inside the ContentPresenter.Style then this time it's Label wich doesn't work...I think it's because Label is a considered as a ContentControl whereas TextBlock is just a FrameworkElement.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue caused by another problem:

There is a strange bug in WPF that prevents styles, defined in merged dictionaries, from being applied to the first element:

https://www.engineeringsolutions.de/wpf-fix-style-is-only-applied-to-first-element/