# Xaml Styles inheritance not working as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am having an issue trying to make use of the BasedOn attribute of Xaml styles. I created a fairly simple style as an example.

The project consists of two main files. MainWindow.xaml and SquareButtonStyle.xaml. SquareButtonStyle makes use of the FontAwesome.WPF project to quickly get some images.

MainWindow is basically a series of buttons with an image inside it and some text.

The goal of this example is to have three different button sizes. A "medium" size, and two variants, "small" and "large", based on the medium size.

The problem is most easily seen with the large variant. The center TextAlignment, Margin and Red text color set from the Medium style, which the large is based on, is lost. It seems that instead of inheriting the style and only override the specific property I am instead inheriting the default style and overriding the property.

What am I doing wrong? It seems the only way to correct this is to not bother with BasedOn, and just make three separate styles with the full list of properties being set. Is there a way to get around this?

SquareButtonStyle.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonMediumStyle">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonMediumStyle}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonSmallStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="55" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="55" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonMediumStyle}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonLargeStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="XamlStyleExample.MainWindow"
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                            mc:Ignorable="d"
                            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="SquareButtonStyle.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel.Resources>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonMediumStyle}" TargetType="Button" />
            </WrapPanel.Resources>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Button 1</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Button 2</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Button 3</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel.Resources>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonSmallStyle}" TargetType="Button" />
            </WrapPanel.Resources>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Button 1</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Button 2</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Button 3</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </WrapPanel>
        <WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel.Resources>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonLargeStyle}" TargetType="Button" />
            </WrapPanel.Resources>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Button 1</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Button 2</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>Button 3</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

## Update

Based Upon a few answers I came up with a solution, but I don't particularly like it. It seems messy.

I now have two keyed styles. One for the StackPanel and one for the TextBlock.

MainWindow.Xaml stays the same but SquaredButtonStyle.xaml now has:

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="SpecialTextBlockStyle">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="MediumNestedStackPanel">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource SpecialTextBlockStyle}" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonMediumStyle">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource MediumNestedStackPanel}">
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>

    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonMediumStyle}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonSmallStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="55" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="55" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- 
            Implicit stack panel style in the scope of SquareButtonMediumStyle 
            inherits from MediumNestedStackPanel, adds stuff
            -->
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource MediumNestedStackPanel}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource SpecialTextBlockStyle}" >
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>

    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonMediumStyle}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonLargeStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource MediumNestedStackPanel}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource SpecialTextBlockStyle}">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: So SquareButtonMediumStyle has a resource that's a StackPanel style, which has its own resources. That's not going to inherit the way you expect via BasedOn with its owner. Your other styles have completely different StackPanel styles, those nested styles have no reason to inherit. I would define that nested StackPanel style resource outside, with a key, and set up a separate BasedOn hierarchy for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those nested `StackPanel` styles aren't going to be involved in the `BasedOn` inheritance for their containing styles. If you want to do that, you'll have to set up a separate inheritance hierarchy for the nested styles:

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="MediumNestedStackPanel">
    <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="fa:ImageAwesome">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="35" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonMediumStyle">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- 
        Implicit stack panel style in the scope of SquareButtonMediumStyle 
        inherits from MediumNestedStackPanel, adds nothing
        -->
        <Style 
            TargetType="StackPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource MediumNestedStackPanel}"
            />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonMediumStyle}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonSmallStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="55" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="55" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- 
    Implicit stack panel style in the scope of SquareButtonMediumStyle 
    inherits from MediumNestedStackPanel, adds stuff
    -->
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource MediumNestedStackPanel}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="fa:ImageAwesome" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type fa:ImageAwesome}}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonMediumStyle}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonLargeStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource MediumNestedStackPanel}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="fa:ImageAwesome" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type fa:ImageAwesome}}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: I am not seeing a different behaviour when I do it like this.  I made sure to copy paste your code to ensure no mistakes. It is difficult to see the margin and center issues on the Small style but you can see that the Red text is not applied. I think this is partly related to the answer mm8 provided but I am still missing some understanding.

Comment: I'll have to test it.

Comment: @Rakshasas How do you make this image awesome thing work? I installed FontAwesome via nuget but nothing's defined.

Comment: Sorry Ed. I take ReSharper for granted sometimes. Make a namespace reference in the MainWindow and SquareButtonStyle `xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"`

Comment: @Rakshasas Yeah, I copied that. Didn't work. Nuget's a worthless POS so I just changed those controls to Label instead of wasting time on it. I just updated my answer. I had left out a couple of parts -- see what it does now.

Comment: You make a good point. The FontAwesome images really aren't important to the question. The textblock colors are doing a better job of showing my issue. I'm going to update the main question to simplify it in a moment. That being said I am still not seeing any change to the text. Only the original Medium buttons have red text. When you say `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"` is that not what it is already doing by default? I feel as if I need to make a special key for each and every control but I also feel that defeats the purpose of doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining an implicit TextBlock style inside the Button style(s), you should set the FontSize, Foreground, ... properties of the Button element itself:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonMediumStyle">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonMediumStyle}" TargetType="Button" x:Key="SquareButtonLargeStyle">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
</Style>
```

Your current approach of using implicit styles for the TextBlocks won't work as you have already discovered. Please refer to the following link for more information about why:

[Wpf, style is not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537575/wpf-style-is-not-being-applied)

Comment: Thank you but I am having a bit of trouble understanding your expanded reading materials. I think it might be because I realized I included another problem in my example without realizing it. Would you know why the ImageAwesome Foreground is not also Red?