# Why button fontsize has no effect when add a TextElement style on Window

Tags: wpf, styles

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextElement}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" >

        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" x:Name="qq">xxx</Button>
        <Button>xxx</Button>
        <Button>xxx</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

code like above

as I know, FontSize of Button is  a DP from TextElement,but why this code no effect?

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

if I change the TextElement to Button everything is ok, why ?

Comment: The following should work:
<Window TextElement.FontSize="50">
...............
</Window>

Comment: Or just `<Window FontSize="50" ...`

Comment: @Clemens yes you are right, but can you tell me why `<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextElement}">` has no effect

Comment: @lsl Reason why your style wasn't working is because it was inside the ` Template` and not as direct property for the control(Button).

Comment: @Gopichandar I can't understand what you say,would you please give me more info about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wpf, style is not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537575/wpf-style-is-not-being-applied)

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476305/wpf-some-styles-not-applied-on-datatemplate-controls) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2009/08/27/implicit-styles-templates-controls-and-frameworkelements/).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `Button`, `TextElement` is not a `Control`. It doesn't inherit from the `System.Windows.Control` class and has no `ControlTemplate` and because of this the implicit style doesn't get applied. Please refer to the following links for more information about this.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2009/08/27/implicit-styles-templates-controls-and-frameworkelements/
[Implicit styles in Application.Resources vs Window.Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035878/implicit-styles-in-application-resources-vs-window-resources)

If you want to define a global text style, you could add an implicit `TextBlock` style to your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you ran into is that property inheritance (from the `Button` control) has a lower precedence than style setters (from the `Style` in `Application`).

Have a look at the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) page on MSDN for a sorted list of all precedences.

To set the global text size you should set `FontSize` on your `MainWindow`. That way you can still use inheritance and styling to override the global text size.